# jQuery arrow keyup function stop while adding a textbox in last row in my table

Tags: javascript, jquery

This is my jquery code and i want to continue my arrow key function.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
 $('input').keyup(function (e)  {

    switch (e.keyCode) {
        case 37:
           // alert('left');      
          $(this).closest('td').prev().find('input').focus();  
            break;
        case 38:
          // alert('up');
             $(this).closest('tr').prev().find('td:eq(' + $(this).closest('td').index() + ')').find('input').focus();
            break;
        case 39:
           // alert('right');
            $(this).closest('td').next().find('input').focus();  
            break;
        case 40:
           // alert('down');            
            var checkRow = $(this).closest('tr').index() + 1;
            var totalRows = $(this).closest('tbody').find('tr').length;

            if (checkRow == totalRows)
            {
                    //here's my additional table row
                     var add= $(this).closest('tr').clone().appendTo($(this).closest('tbody').parent());
                     //i want to continue arrows key for additional textbox in my new row. 
            }

             $(this).closest('tr').next().find('td:eq(' + $(this).closest('td').index() + ')').find('input').focus();   

            break;
    } }); });
```

Comment: can you share your sample in jsfiddle

Comment: Hi Arin here my JSfiddle  sample . [JSFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/rhicks_28/6onmt937/) .

Answer (score 0):

You don't add `keyup` event to newly created `input`s. Instead of `$('input').keyup(fn)` which adds event only to existing `input`s use `$(document).on('keyup', 'input', fn)`. It listens to the document and triggers when it reaches every `input` selector. Examples in [API documentation](http://api.jquery.com/on/).

Comment: $(document).on('keyup', function(){
   $("#dataTable tbody tr").on("keyup", "input", function (e)

Comment: It won't work properly. Every time you press a key, a new event will be added. Use just `$("#dataTable").on("keyup", "input", function (e) { ... });` - [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/6onmt937/6/).